# v-progress-linear changes value on click

Tags: vue.js

My `<v-progress-linear>` kept changing on click, and I want to prevent that.

```
 <v-progress-linear
   v-model="progress"
   color="primary"
   height="20"
 >
```

Fix: I don't use v-model.
Just use :value

```
<v-progress-linear
   :value="progress"
   color="primary"
   height="20" 
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encounter the same issue and I solved it by a hack using a CSS property `pointer-events` which let the progress-linear element to not react any pointer events:

```html
 <v-progress-linear
   v-model="progress"
   color="primary"
   height="20"
   style="pointer-events: none"
 >
```